# Bootstrap Javascript not working on live website

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been facing some problems in my website. I have a lot of js files in my web server, but the *bootstrap.js* file does not work. Here is the **[link](http://arqetech.net/js/bootstrap.js)** to the ressource and it also blocks AddThis sharing tools. I have no Idea how this is happening!

here are the main js which I'm using:

```
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/secondary.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

And here is the **[website link](http://arqetech.net/)**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have to load jquery-latest.js **before** the others. Bootstrap requires jquery to be loaded first.

Comment: I already have it: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No, you're loading jquery 2.1.3 *after* the other four. And why are you loading jquery twice, anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ is undefined error in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313612/is-undefined-error-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks! for your help. Yes and when I click on It on the console it takes me to the code!

Comment: And just highlights the problem in bootstrap.js: `if (!jQuery) { throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery"); }` Instead of showing the problem inside the Html

Comment: But anyway, Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

You need to load the jQuery script first followed by the Bootstrap js and finally the custom scripts last like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="http://arqetech.net/js/secondary.js"></script>
```

Either use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

**BUT NOT BOTH**

Comment: Glad I could help Arqetech :)

Answer (score 0):

You must load jquery before bootstrap because bootstrap use jquery. If any custom script use jquery too....jquery must be loaded before that custom script.

I recommend you that use minified version of all js files because it increase your web site performance

https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-10-minify-javascript-7208.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jQuery being a pre-requisite for Bootstrap's Javascript to work (as mentioned in the previous answers), it is also worth noting that as of v 3.3.6,

> "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but
>   lower than version 3"

(just in case you thought using the latest version of jQuery would be better, as I did.)